# Evaluate $\operatorname{Rad}(A/\operatorname{Rad}(A))$ in a Banach algebra

Tags: banach-algebras

I've asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969152/calculate-operatornamerada-operatornamerada-in-a-banach-algebra)

Let $A$ be a Banach algebra with identity $e_A$,  I'd like to find

> $\operatorname{Rad}(A/\operatorname{Rad}(A)).$

whre we define

> $\operatorname{Rad}(A)=\{a\in A:e_A-ba \in \text{InvA},b\in A\}$

I think it's equal $\operatorname{Rad}(A)$

but I didn't get any hint  how to prove that, please let me know how to prove that

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your link seems to be to a different question; and this question belongs better on MSE anyway.

Comment: Have you considered the case where Rad(A) has codimension 1 in A?

Comment: @Dear  Yemon Choi , you are right I correct it